# Set a responsive image as a background in an html, with a menu on top

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, background-image

I have an html that with CSS shows an image responsively.

I want an image to be displayed fully on a screen and menu on top of it, so there won't be any scrolling when the menu is opened:

I would like to add a nav bar on top of that image, meaning that the image would be in the background
Right now, if I add a navbar, it doesn't give me that effect

I've tried to display the image in a div background, but that ruins the responsiveness...

How do I make the image to be "in the background" for any object I will display on top of it, without ruining the css?

Below is the working code of the page so far:

```css
        .content {
          padding-right: 0px;
          padding-left: 0px;
        }
    
        img {
            max-width: 100%;
        }
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script
              src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
              integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<div class="container-fluid ">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1 content">

        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97600&w=350&h=600">

    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: add Jquery: see in F12 the error: `Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery",`

Comment: Added to the code

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve here?

Comment: I want an image to be displayed fully on a screen and menu on top of it, so there won't be any scrolling when the menu is opened

Comment: @GuyL Please do not use signatures in posts.  For more information, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior).